# How to define aliases of locales in typesafe-i18n?

Tags: javascript, typescript, internationalization, locale, chinese-locale

## Motivation

Chinese language has historically multiple language codes (RFC 5646 with ISO-639
zh). Practically, the most frequently used ones are `zh-CN` (for Simplified Hanzi Script of Chinese Mandarin language mainly used in PRC, etc.), `zh-TW` (for Traditional Hanzi Script of Chinese Mandarin language mainly used in Taiwan, etc.), `zh` (usually equivalent of `zh-CN`). There are also less used `zh-HanS` and `zh-HanT` that are almost share the same effect as `zh-CN` and `zh-TW` respectively with regions not specified.

The new ECMAScript `Intl` API will give different display names for all those codes, but will carry their semantically regional and political message. I want my application to be neutral so I would like to use `zh-HanS` and `zh-HanT` instead of `zh-CN` and `zh-TW`.

## Problem

Most of modern browsers will always use `Accept-Language: zh-CN; zh;` for `zh-CN`/`zh-HanS`, and `Accept-Language: zh-TW; zh;` for `zh-TW`/`zh-HanT` in HTTP headers. Since zh-HanS/zh-HanT are not used, if I use them in my application as `src/i18n/zh-HanS`/`src/i18n/zh-HanT`, `detectLocale(initAcceptLanguageHeaderDetector({headers})` of `typesafe-i18n` will fail to find the correct locale, tries to fallback to `zh`, but then fail and fallback to baseLocale (often `en`).

## Question

How can I make aliases for them and let the detector fallback to the correct language?

Answer (score 0):

The generated `detectLocale` function defined as following in `src/i18n/i18n-util.ts` will use `locales` (a generated variable showing a list of locale files).

```js
// src/i18n/i18n-util.ts
import { detectLocale as detectLocaleFn } from 'typesafe-i18n/detectors'

// [...]

export const locales: Locales[] = [
    'en',
    'ja',
    'zh-HanS',
    'zh-HanT'
]

// [...]

export const detectLocale = (...detectors: LocaleDetector[]) => detectLocaleFn<Locales>(baseLocale, locales, ...detectors)
```

So we need to `detectLocaleFn` above intead (`detectLocale from 'typesafe-i18n/detectors'`)

In your detection code,

```js
import detectLocale from 'typesafe-i18n/detectors'

// [...]

// Alias table
const LOCALE_ALIAS = new Map<string, Locales>([
  ['zh-CN', 'zh-HanS'],
  ['zh-TW', 'zh-HanT'],
  ['zh-HK', 'zh-HanT'],
  ['zh', 'zh-HanS'],
])
// for initAcceptLanguageHeaderDetector
const headers = getHeaders(request)
const acceptLanguageDetector = initAcceptLanguageHeaderDetector({ headers })

// detection
const locale = detectLocale<Locales>(baseLocale, [...locales, ...LOCALE_ALIAS.keys()] as Locales[], acceptLanguageDetector)

const aliasedLocale = LOCALE_ALIAS.get(locale) ?? locale
console.log(`Detected locale: ${locale}, aliased to: ${aliasedLocale}`)
```